# Modelling producer-consumer semantics with typeclasses?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, typeclass, producer-consumer

If some entities in a system can function as producers of data or events, and other entities can function as consumers, does it make sense to externalize these "orthogonal concerns" into Producer and Consumer typeclasses?

I can see that the Haskell Pipes library uses this approach, and appreciate this question may look pretty basic for people coming from a Haskell background, but would be interested in a Scala perspective and examples because I don't see a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into [this article](http://matt.might.net/articles/pipelined-nonblocking-extensible-web-server-with-coroutines/) by Matt Might.

It gives you a simple implementation of `Producer`, `Consumer`, `Transducer` (Pipe in the haskell library you mentioned) and an example on how to use them to create a web server.

Basically each `Producer` extends `Runnable` and have a private buffer to output elements. The buffer is a java `ArrayBlockingQueue` which is thread-safe.

Each `Consumer` is also a `Runnable` and has an input buffer using a similar architecture.

When you chain a `Consumer` to a `Producer`, you create another `Runnable`. 
On start it will start the `Producer` and the `Consumer` (they are Runnable) and will transfer the data between them.

When you chain a `Transducer` to a `Producer` it creates a new `Producer`.

So if you follow his implementation you should be able to write in the fashion of haskell:

```
listen ==> connect ==> process ==> reply
```

Here is some code copied and improved from the link above:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue

trait Coroutine extends Runnable {
    def start() {
        val myThread = new Thread(this)
        myThread.start()
    }
}

trait Producer[O] extends Coroutine {
     private val outputs = new ArrayBlockingQueue[O](1024)
     protected def put(output: O): Unit = outputs.put(output)
     def next(): O = outputs.take()

     def ==>[I >: O](consumer: Consumer[I]): Coroutine = {
         val that = this
         new Coroutine {
             def run() {
                 while (true) { val o = that.next(); consumer.accept(o) }
             }

             override def start() {
                 that.start()
                 consumer.start()
                 super.start()
             }
         }
     }
}

trait Consumer[I] extends Coroutine {
    private val inputs = new ArrayBlockingQueue[I] (1024)
    def accept(input : I): Unit = inputs.put(input)
    protected def get(): I = inputs.take()
}
```

And here is how you could use it:

```
case class IntProducer(zero: Int) extends Producer[Int]{
    def run(): Unit = {
         var i = zero
         while(true) { put(i); i += 1 }
    }
}

object Printer extends Consumer[Any]{
    def run(): Unit = {
         while(true) { println(get()) }
    }
}

val pip = IntProducer(0) ==> Printer
pip.start()
```

To see more example and how to handle the `Transducer̀  look at [my Gist](https://gist.github.com/gwenzek/649444d583d8dc5e1596).